# Limiting Outbound SMB traffic on Windows server 2012

Tags: server-message-block

Hi i have a NAS running Windows server 2012 r2
And a number of PXE-booting clients running windows 7, pxe boot depends heavily on network traffic.
Unfortunately my clients need SMB share from NAS server as well. 
And when the network traffic is high, some clients fail to boot.

Therefore i'd like to limit outbound SMB traffic from my NAS.
Googled a bit but there's no clear solution.
I tried smbbandwidthlimit but apparently it only affects specifically for domain replication,hyper-V live migrations and similar operations, and not designed for client OS's.

So is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Found the answer, got it to work by setting this on the server http://fixmyitsystem.com/2013/12/QOS01.html?m=1 Cheers

Comment: Answer : New-NetQosPolicy -Name "FileCopy" -SMB -ThrottleRateActionBitsPerSecond 20MB